High CPU Usage with less in Forward Scroll Mode (F) After SSH Disconnect on Gentoo Linux (OpenRC)
I'm encountering an issue where the less command consumes 100% of one CPU core after an SSH session is disconnected. Below are the detailed steps to reproduce this behavior:

Log in to the server:
ssh john@server-example


Switch to another user:
sudo su - testuser


Open a file using less:
less /var/log/somefile.log


Enter Forward Scroll Mode (F): (This mode continuously monitors the file, similar to tail -f. )

Terminate the SSH session abruptly (on the client side):

Using the SSH escape sequence: Enter ~ ., or killing the SSH process on the client machine.



After disconnecting the SSH session, the less process remains active on the server and consumes 100% CPU. When checking with ps -ef, the output shows:
testuser   9930  9906 35 22:54 ?        00:02:05 less /var/log/somefile.log

Additional Information:

This behavior only occurs after switching users (e.g., from john to testuser).
If I run less directly as the john user, the less process is terminated as expected when the SSH session disconnects.
The log file is small and static (no new data is being written to it).
huponexit Setting: I've tried enabling shopt -s huponexit both in the initial SSH session and after switching users (sudo su - testuser), but it doesn't resolve the issue.
Environment Details:

OS: Gentoo Linux
Init System: OpenRC



Why does less enter a high CPU state when the SSH session disconnects after switching users?
Is there a way to automatically terminate processes like less when the user session ends, particularly after switching users?
Any insights or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
